# Mootools Counter countdown not work

Tags: javascript, mootools

I got a mootools countdown [here](http://mootools.net/forge/p/countdown), but it look like not work
I got an error message `Uncaught ReferenceError: PeriodicalExecuter is not defined` in CountDown.js line 36 (`this.timer = new PeriodicalExecuter(this.update.bind(this), (this.options.frequency || 1000) / 1000);`)

The class `PeriodicalExecuter` seem not included in mootools. Hope someone have the code of `PeriodicalExecuter` or know where I could find it.

The class `PeriodicalExecuter` should at least include function `stop()` and `registerCallback()`

Here is the code of CountDown.js for your reference

```
/*
---
script: CountDown.js
license: MIT-style license.
description: CountDown - a mootools countdown implementation.
copyright: Copyright (c) 2008 Thierry Bela
authors: [Thierry Bela]

requires: 
  core:1.2.3: 
  - Events
  - Options
provides: [CountDown]
...
*/

var CountDown = new Class({

    /* 

        options: {

            onChange: $empty,
            onComplete: $empty,
            date: null,
            frequency: 1000 //define the update frequency (in ms), default to 1000
        },

        */
    Implements: [Options, Events],
    initialize: function (options) {

        this.setOptions(options);
        if(!this.options.date instanceof Date) this.options.date = new Date(this.options.date);

        this.timer = new PeriodicalExecuter(this.update.bind(this), (this.options.frequency || 1000) / 1000);
    },
    stop: function () {

        this.timer.stop();          
        return this
    },
    start: function () {

        this.timer.registerCallback();          
        return this
    },
    update: function () {

        var millis = Math.max(0, this.options.date.getTime() - new Date().getTime()),
        time = Math.floor(millis / 1000),
        stop = time == 0,
        countdown = {

            days: Math.floor(time / (60 * 60 * 24)), 
            time: time,
            millis: millis
        };

        time %= (60 * 60 * 24);

        countdown.hours = Math.floor(time / (60 * 60));
        time %= (60 * 60);
        countdown.minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
        countdown.second = time % 60;

        this.fireEvent('onChange', countdown);

        if(stop) {

            this.timer.stop();
            this.fireEvent('onComplete');
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT**
I am using Mootools version 1.4.5 with compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the class code to use standard methods.

It looks like `.registerCallback` is just a function that starts the timer, ie. `setInterval`.
Clearly `.stop` stops the timer, ie. `clearInterval`.
The only thing the `PeriodicalExecuter` class appears to do is to pass the arguments you gave it on instantiation to the `setInterval` call every time.

That's about enough information to implement it yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/pspygear/source/browse/trunk/trunk/PspyGear/html/osgata/scripts/PeriodicalExecuter.js?r=114
Finally, I find the js file in above site

BTW, thanks @Reanimation.
The source code is similar to what you say